# Java troubles reading input from console

Tags: java, buffer, flush

I've been storming ahead with my Java work at University (I've never done Java prior to this) but I'm stuck with inputs a little bit.  The task is to write a basic program that allows the user to input their name, house number, road name and town but when it gets to inputting the road name, it seems to skip and doesn't allow you to enter anything for town.

Now, I've tried a flush buffer but that didn't work since it just overwrites what was input.  For example, I put the flush buffer after the road name input and that input would then be ignored.

The problem could also be that white space is breaking things despite me using nextLine and not next.

Here's my code;

```
import java.util.*;

public class AddressProj {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Please input your surname: ");
        String name = myKeyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Please input your house number: ");
        int houseNumber = myKeyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Please input your road name: ");
        String roadName = myKeyboard.nextLine();
        myKeyboard.nextLine(); //Flush buffer

        System.out.printf("Please input your town: ");
        String town = myKeyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Surname: " + name + "\nHouse Number: " + houseNumber + "\nRoad Name: " + roadName + "\nTown: " + town + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth do you mean by a 'flash buffer'?

Comment: @bmargulies _flush_ a buffer, I suppose.

Comment: @bmargulies uh, apologies.  flush buffer.  it's getting late.

Comment: I know flushing the buffer is only usable after entering an integer which is why I'm rather stuck on what to do here.

Comment: why do you think that a call to nextLine() is flushing a buffer? My advice is not to connect a scanner directly to System.in. But more generally, this sort of Console IO is very rare in modern practical programming.

Comment: @bmargulies This is how flushing a buffer was explained by my lecturer.  Either way, I've fixed it.  As I said, flushing a buffer is used after inputting an integer and in my tired state, I forgot to actually try it after the integer input which was the issue.  I think it's time to sleep.  In terms of using a scanner directly connected to System.in, this is what I've been taught so far and I'm assuming that if there's issues with this and it's not practical in the real world, we'll be taught a different, more efficient method.

Comment: All's well that ends well. In the real world, people don't use Java programs that talk to the console, so none of this comes up. You can tell your instructor that the CTO of a company that hires Java programmers thinks that this exercise is pretty pointless :-)

Comment: @bmargulies You know, I think I will let him know.  I mean, I'm also a student rep so if I find any module content to be irrelevant I can bring it up at meetings to discuss replacing it with something more practical.  Although, this is still the very basics of Java so hopefully the stuff we are taught later on is more real world based.

Answer (score 2):

nextInt() does not read an entire line. Just an int. So the NL you are entering to end the house number is left to be eaten by the next thing.

I strongly recommend something more like:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "utf-8");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Then, for each item:

```
reader.readLine();
```

to obtain the user's input, and then parse as needed with things like Integer.parseInt.